# Accessing @Published variable in Toggle SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a published variable isToggled, that I would like to toggle individually for each notification. For reference, trying to simulate the apple notification system, where a user can schedule local notificiations, enable or disable them.

My issue is I'm receiving the following error

> Cannot convert value of type 'Published.Publisher' to expected
> argument type 'Binding'

I tried a few solutions online, but yet to find a solid solution

```
ForEach(notificationManager.notifications.uniqueByNotificationIdentifier) { notification in
                        VStack {
                            HStack {
                                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                    Text(reminderLogic.formatNotificationTime(trigger: notification.trigger))
                                        .bold()
                                        .font(.title)
                                    Text(notification.body)
                                        .font(.title3)
                                        .padding(.top, 1)
                                        .foregroundColor(Color("accentUserText"))
                                    Text(notification.savedDays.joined(separator: ", "))
                                        .foregroundColor(Color("accentUserText"))
                                }
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading) // Ensure consistent frame width and alignment

                                Spacer()

                                Toggle("Show welcome message", isOn: $notification.isToggled)
                                .onChange(of: notification.isToggled) { newValue in
                                   if newValue {
                                       // If toggled on, schedule the notification
                                     print("jfj")
                                   } else {
                                       // If toggled off, cancel the notification
                                      print("jeeeeee")
                                   }
                               }
                                    .padding(.trailing, 10)            .padding(.trailing, 10)
```

and then my view B which is the published variable

```
class NotificationModel: Identifiable, ObservableObject {
    @Published var isToggled: Bool = true 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn’t give the declaration of `notification`. I assume it is something like this:

```
@ObservedObject var notification: NotificationModel
```

Or possibly you declared it `@StateObject` instead of `@ObservableObject`.

Anyway, you wrote this in your question:

> ```
> Toggle("Toggle me ", isOn: notification.isToggled)
> ```

But I do not believe that is what you wrote in Xcode. Because (assuming you declared `notification` as I guessed) then you would get this error:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'Bool' to expected argument type 'Binding<Bool>'
```

To get the error you included in your question, you need to write this code:

```
Toggle("Toggle me ", isOn: notification.$isToggled)
```

The correct code to write, to get a `Binding<Bool>`, is this code:

```
Toggle("Toggle me ", isOn: $notification.isToggled)
```

Notice that the `$` goes before the `ObservedObject`, not before the `Published` property.

Comment: I actually just edited my question. Thank you for the response, I'm actually looking to access the individual model that I'm calling in my ForEach. So not necessarily going off the StateObject